# Issue on jQuery Ui Autocomplete From URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Can you please let me know how I ca use the jQuery UI Autocomplete getting data from URL? currently I have a code which works fine foe me as:

```
var data = [
    {"label":"Aragorn", "actor":"Viggo Mortensen"},
    {"label":"Arwen", "actor":"Liv Tyler"},
    {"label":"Bilbo Baggins", "actor":"Ian Holm"},
    {"label":"Boromir", "actor":"Sean Bean"},
    {"label":"Frodo Baggins", "actor":"Elijah Wood"},
    {"label":"Gandalf", "actor":"Ian McKellen"},
    {"label":"Gimli", "actor":"John Rhys-Davies"},
    {"label":"Gollum", "actor":"Andy Serkis"},
    {"label":"Legolas", "actor":"Orlando Bloom"},
    {"label":"Meriadoc Merry Brandybuck", "actor":"Dominic Monaghan"},
    {"label":"Peregrin Pippin Took", "actor":"Billy Boyd"},
    {"label":"Samwise Gamgee", "actor":"Sean Astin"}
    ];

$(function() {

    $( "#search" ).autocomplete(
    {
        source:data,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.label + " / " + ui.item.actor );
            return false;
        }
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a><strong>" + item.label + "</strong> / " + item.actor + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };      

});
```

and HTML:

```
 <input type="text" id="search" />
```

**BUT** I need to get the data from stored json file on server(data.json.txt) instead of putting on the page. I tried to change `source:data,` to `source:data.json.txt,` but didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `$.get()` to fetch your data.

```
$(function () {
    var data;
    $.get('data.json.txt', function (response) {
        data = response;
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#search").val(ui.item.label + " / " + ui.item.actor);
                return false;
            }
        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a><strong>" + item.label + "</strong> / " + item.actor + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
    }, 'json');
});
```

Make sure the URL is correct in here `$.get('/path/to/data.json.txt')`.

Comment: Hi Magnus, Thanks for reply but honesty I got lost.where should I use the $.get() inside the .autocomplete()?

Comment: so wehere is the URL?

Comment: New edit! Should hopefully work now. I don't think it would load the data before running autocomplete before.

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is then :( Try accessing the json file by pasting the URL in the browser, just to see if you can access it at all. The basic concept above should be correct, so now you just have to make it work on your end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43795/discussion-between-behseini-and-magnus-engdal)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't around anymore for the chat invitation. Hope you get it to work and have a merry christmas!